# I want to make sure that some buttons are pressed in the correct order, how do I do this?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Hey just trying to create a basic logic game using pyqt that requires some buttons to be pressed in the correct order to open a 'safe' how could I do this whilst using an array? I am pretty knew to this stuff so apologies if it is very easy!

Comment: Can you explain what you've done so far and provide the associated code?

Answer (score 0):

Every Time someone presses the button, add which button they pressed to the array ("1" if they pressed the 1st button, "2" if they pressed the 2nd button), once the size of this array is equal to how many numbers are in the code, check to see if all the numbers in the array match all the numbers in the code.

Comment: Sorry I guess that maybe asking how to create an array would have been a better way of phrasing my question?

Comment: `ArrayName=[]` creates a blank array. `ArrayName.append(value)` adds `value` to `ArrayName`